# Can you specify what port Remote Desktop tries to connect to?

Tags: remote-desktop

The Remote Desktop client attempts to connect to port 3389 on the server machine.

If you want it to connect to different port you have to specify it in the address, eg. 100.10.10.1:3390

Is there way to change the default port it tries to connect to so that you don't have to specify it in the address?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the portnumber by modifying the registry key:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber**

In mstsc you can connect to the host just the way you expected. (eg: 100.10.10.1:3390).

Comment: ZEDA-NL's answer is correct, but what all(!) guides on the Internet, including MS FixIt, forgot to mention is that you have to create a rule in the Windows firewall to let the connection through.

Comment: Yes! that was my downfall. I did a reboot after changing the port, and the firewall was still blocking the new port, while i was 300km away from the computer !